# How to create a symbolic link dynamically with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

I have a laravel 5.8 app in a `staging` subdomain sitting on a bluehost VPS. At the moment everything works fine except for not being able to view the images uploaded as the files are stored in the app `storage` folder.

To fix this, I need to create a symbolic link between the app `storage` and `public_html` folders. So I added a `symlink.php` file in `public_html/staging` with this content in it

```
<?php
symlink('/home/maindomain/staging/storage/app/public', '/home/maindomain/public_html/staging');
```

Making a get request to `https://staging.maindomain.com/symlink.php` should create the link and add the `storage` folder to `public_html/staging` directory.

Unfortunately that is not happening and I can't figure out why. Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$result = app('files')->link('/home/maindomain/staging/storage/app/public', '/home/maindomain/public_html/staging');

if ($result !== true)
{
    // you probably have a permission error
}
```